# Reflection Exception : Class does not exist for manually added class

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.8

I added a seeder (copied from elsewhere and pasted) to my application and included the call in the Database Seeder run() function. I get the exception above even though the class exists.

I suspected that maybe some files may have been cached so i cleared the application cache but i still get the same error.

DatabaseSeeder.php

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;

class DatabaseSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Seed the application's database.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        // $this->call(CustomersTableSeeder::class);
        $this->call(RolesTableSeeder::class);
        $this->call(ManagerStatesTableSeeder::class);
        $this->call(ManagersTableSeeder::class);
        $this->call(CountsTableSeeder::class);
        $this->call(CategoriesTableSeeder::class);
    }
}
```

Seeder file CategoriesTableSeeder.php

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;

class CategoriesTableSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        \DB::table('categories')->insert([
            [
                'description' => 'Perfumes and Deo',
                'slug' => 'perfumes-and-deo',
                'parent' => 0,
                'level' => 1,
                'cna' => '2|',
                'created_at' => \Carbon\Carbon::now(),
                'updated_at' => \Carbon\Carbon::now(),
            ],
            [
                'description' => 'Perfumes',
                'slug' => 'perfumes',
                'parent' => 1,
                'level' => 2,
                'cna' => NULL,
                'created_at' => \Carbon\Carbon::now(),
                'updated_at' => \Carbon\Carbon::now(),
            ]
        ]);
    }
}
```

Error:

> ReflectionException  : Class CategoriesTableSeeder does not exist
>
> at C:\wamp\www\ma-sales-tracker\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php:788
>
> Exception trace:
>
> 1   ReflectionClass::__construct("CategoriesTableSeeder")
>         C:\wamp\www\ma-sales-tracker\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php:788
>
> 2   Illuminate\Container\Container::build("CategoriesTableSeeder")
>         C:\wamp\www\ma-sales-tracker\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php:667

Any ideas on what might be causing this? Thanks in advance guys

Comment: Please can you detail the path/filename of the CategoriesTableSeeder class?

Comment: database\seeds\CategoriesTableSeeder.php

Comment: Hi @Ekow as @dparoli i see you don't write the `use` instruction try by adding thems.

Comment: Composer dump-autoload if you added it manually. I would recommend using artisan commands next time cause it does it for you.

Comment: try to run composer dump-autoload , but it's strange it should'nt be needed in newest versions

Comment: @pietro yikes. I'm not sure i understand. Can you elaborate. Thanks a milli

Comment: @AlexMac I agree 100%, will do so always from now. And yeah it worked! You guys are awesome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I run Composer dump-autoload and voila! Worked as a charm. Also as suggested by Alex Mac, always generate Seeders with artisan commands.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you create any new file, always run following commands :-

```
composer dumpa // composer dump-autoload
php artisan optimize:clear // php artisan optimize:clear
```

because in bootstrap folder it keeps a track of each files and other configurations, etc.